# Python Flask SQLAlchemy: "Can't determine relationship direction... for nested relationship

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a double-dynamic form-page where both form-items and select-options (in the drop down menus) are read from a database depending on the chosen organisation and the language preference of the user.

In the code, user_data_types represents the form items, and response_options represents the drop down menu alternatives.

The error message I get is:
Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'UserDataType.response_option_names' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent
nor the child's mapped tables

What is meant with this error message, and what is it that I'm missing / how to fix it? The problem seems to be in the UserDataType class definition(?)

Python code part:

```
org = Org.query.filter_by(slug=slug).first() #works fine

language_pref = logged_in_user.language_pref_id #works fine

user_data_types = OrgDataType.query.filter_by(org_id=org.id).with_entities(OrgDataType.user_data_type_id) #works fine

user_data_type_details = UserDataType.query.filter(UserDataType.id.in_(user_data_types)).\
filter_by(language_id=language_pref).\
join(UserDataTypeResponseOption, UserDataType.id == UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id).\
join(ResponseOption, UserDataTypeResponseOption.response_option_id == ResponseOption.id).\
filter_by(language_id=language_pref)\
#I think this works, see equivalent(?) SQL query further below

if request.method == "GET":
    return render_template("myform/pref_edit.html", user_data_type_details=user_data_type_details)
```

HTML code part:

```
{% for user_data_type_detail in user_data_type_details %}
  <div>
    <select name="user_data_type_detail.user_data_type_name">
    {% for response_option in user_data_type_detail.reponse_option_names %}
      <option value="{{ response_option.response_option_name }}">{{ response_option.response_option_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Database class definitions (with UserDataTypeResponseOption linking the other two together):

```
class UserDataType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_data_type_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    response_option_names = db.relationship("ResponseOption", primaryjoin="UserDataType.id==UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id", viewonly=True)

class UserDataTypeResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type_response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    user_data_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_data_type.id'))
    response_option_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('response_option.id'))

class ResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    response_option_name = db.Column(db.Text)
```

Tables created in SQLite DB Browser are as per:

```
CREATE TABLE "user_data_type" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "language_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "user_data_type_name"   TEXT,
    "user_data_type_description"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id","language_id")
);

CREATE TABLE "user_data_type_response_option" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "user_data_type_id" INTEGER,
    "response_option_id"    INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("response_option_id") REFERENCES "response_option"("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("user_data_type_id") REFERENCES "user_data_type"("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "response_option" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "language_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "response_option_name"  TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id","language_id")
);
```

In SQLite DB Browser I can run this SQL query...

```
select user_data_type.id, user_data_type_name, response_option_id, response_option_name
   from user_data_type
   join user_data_type_response_option
      on user_data_type.id = user_data_type_response_option.user_data_type_id
   join response_option
      on user_data_type_response_option.response_option_id = response_option.id
   where user_data_type.id = 1 and user_data_type.language_id = 2 and response_option.language_id = 2
```

...which gives me the following result, which is what I think I need to render the form-page.

id | user_data_type | response_option_id | response_option_name
1   E-mail  1   No e-mails please
1   E-mail  2   Only fun e-mails
1   E-mail  3   All e-mails please

Answer (score 1):

The error

`Can't determine relationship direction for relationship 'UserDataType.response_option_names' - foreign key columns are present in neither the parent nor the child's mapped tables`

is telling you that a foreign key relation from `ResponseOption` to `UserDataType` was expected and was not found.

This foreign key is expected as you defined the column `response_option_names = db.relationship("ResponseOption", ...)` on the `UserDataType` table. It is correct in this Many-to-Many scenario not to have such a foreign key as you will be relating `UserDataType` and `ResponseOption` using the association table `UserDataTypeResponseOption`.

Following the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object), you can fix this by changing

```py
response_option_names = db.relationship("ResponseOption", primaryjoin="UserDataType.id==UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id", viewonly=True)
```

to

```py
associations = db.relationship("UserDataTypeResponseOption", primaryjoin="UserDataType.id==UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id", viewonly=True)
```

You also need to add a new relationship from `UserDataTypeResponseOption` to `ResponseOption` like this:

```py
response_option = db.relationship("ResponseOption")
```

Now your query

```py
user_data_type_details = UserDataType.query.filter(UserDataType.id.in_(user_data_types)).\
filter_by(language_id=language_pref).\
join(UserDataTypeResponseOption, UserDataType.id == UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id).\
join(ResponseOption, UserDataTypeResponseOption.response_option_id == ResponseOption.id).\
filter_by(language_id=language_pref)\
```

will work fine, but please notice that you don't have direct access to `ResponseOption`s from each `UserDataType` element. You'll need to go through `UserDataTypeResponseOption`:

```py
for udt in user_data_type_details:
    print('user data type: ', udt)
    for assoc in udt.associations:
        print('response option: ', assoc.response_option.response_option_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
user data type:  <UserDataType 1, 1>
response option:  No e-mails please
response option:  Only fun e-mails
response option:  All e-mails please
```

But we are not done yet. At this point, if you look at the database design, you can see that it is not really usable for more than one language, as the association table knows nothing about languages and you can only link `UserDataType` to `ResponseOption` by their corresponding ids and those ids are not necessary unique across those tables.

One solution would be to re-design your tables so that the association table also knows about the language id of both `UserDataType` and `ResponseOption`. For that you wold need to add two `ForeignKeyConstraint` constraints to the `UserDataTypeResponseOption` as this is the way of creating foreign keys with multiple columns in `SQLAlchemy`. I also removed the column `id` from the association table and marked the rest of the columns as primary keys:

```py
class UserDataType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_data_type_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    associations = db.relationship("UserDataTypeResponseOption", viewonly=True)


class ResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    response_option_name = db.Column(db.Text)


class UserDataTypeResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type_response_option'
    user_data_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_data_type_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option = db.relationship("ResponseOption")
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([user_data_type_id, user_data_type_language_id],
                                           [UserDataType.id, UserDataType.language_id]),
                      ForeignKeyConstraint([response_option_id, response_option_language_id],
                                           [ResponseOption.id, ResponseOption.language_id]),
                      {})
```

And now you can have multiple languages.

#### Direct access to the `ResponseOption`s from `UserDataType` objects.

`SQLAlchemy` provides a way to access `ResponseOption`s directly by using the Association Proxy extension (read [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html)):

***This extension allows the configuration of attributes which will access two “hops” with a single access, one “hop” to the associated object, and a second to a target attribute.***

But this comes with a caveat:

***Warning The association object pattern does not coordinate changes with a separate relationship that maps the association table as “secondary”.***

As you are not modifying any entities, you can safely use the extension like this:

```py
class UserDataType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_data_type_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    response_options = db.relationship("ResponseOption", secondary="user_data_type_response_option", viewonly=True)  # added secondary


class ResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    response_option_name = db.Column(db.Text)


class UserDataTypeResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type_response_option'
    user_data_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_data_type_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option = db.relationship("ResponseOption", backref="parent_associations")  # added backref
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([user_data_type_id, user_data_type_language_id],
                                           [UserDataType.id, UserDataType.language_id]),
                      ForeignKeyConstraint([response_option_id, response_option_language_id],
                                           [ResponseOption.id, ResponseOption.language_id]),
                      {})
```

```py
for udt in user_data_type_details:
    print('user data type: ', udt)
    for ro in udt.response_options:
        print('response option: ', ro.response_option_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
user data type:  <UserDataType 1, 1>
response option:  No e-mails please
response option:  Only fun e-mails
response option:  All e-mails please
```

#### Complete code

app.py

```py
import logging

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import os

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKeyConstraint

sh = logging.StreamHandler()
sh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, handlers=[sh])
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

app = Flask(__name__)
db_name = 'test.db'
if os.path.isfile(db_name):
    os.remove(db_name)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + db_name
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class UserDataType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_data_type_name = db.Column(db.Text)
    response_options = db.relationship("ResponseOption", secondary="user_data_type_response_option", viewonly=True)  # added secondary


class ResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    response_option_name = db.Column(db.Text)


class UserDataTypeResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type_response_option'
    user_data_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_data_type_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    response_option = db.relationship("ResponseOption", backref="parent_associations")  # added backref
    __table_args__ = (ForeignKeyConstraint([user_data_type_id, user_data_type_language_id],
                                           [UserDataType.id, UserDataType.language_id]),
                      ForeignKeyConstraint([response_option_id, response_option_language_id],
                                           [ResponseOption.id, ResponseOption.language_id]),
                      {})


db.create_all()


language_id = 1
udt_id = 1
db.session.add(UserDataType(id=udt_id, language_id=language_id, user_data_type_name='E-mail'))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=1, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='No e-mails please'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=1, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=2, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='Only fun e-mails'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=2, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=3, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='All e-mails please'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=3, response_option_language_id=language_id))

udt_id = 2
db.session.add(UserDataType(id=udt_id, language_id=language_id, user_data_type_name='Calls'))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=4, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='No calls please'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=4, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=5, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='Only business calls'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=5, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=6, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='All calls please'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=6, response_option_language_id=language_id))

language_id = 2
udt_id = 1
db.session.add(UserDataType(id=udt_id, language_id=language_id, user_data_type_name='E-mail (lang 2)'))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=1, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='No e-mails please(lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=1, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=2, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='Only fun e-mails(lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=2, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=3, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='All e-mails please(lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=3, response_option_language_id=language_id))

udt_id = 2
db.session.add(UserDataType(id=udt_id, language_id=language_id, user_data_type_name='Calls (lang 2)'))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=4, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='No calls please (lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=4, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=5, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='Only business calls (lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=5, response_option_language_id=language_id))
db.session.add(ResponseOption(id=6, language_id=language_id, response_option_name='All calls please (lang 2)'))
db.session.add(UserDataTypeResponseOption(user_data_type_id=udt_id, user_data_type_language_id=language_id, response_option_id=6, response_option_language_id=language_id))

db.session.commit()


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

    language_pref = request.args.get('lang')

    user_data_type_details = UserDataType.query. \
        filter_by(language_id=language_pref). \
        join(UserDataTypeResponseOption, UserDataType.id == UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id). \
        join(ResponseOption, UserDataTypeResponseOption.response_option_id == ResponseOption.id). \
        filter_by(language_id=language_pref)

    for udt in user_data_type_details:
        print('user data type: ', udt)
        for ro in udt.response_options:
            print('response option: ', ro.response_option_name)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("myform/pref_edit.html", user_data_type_details=user_data_type_details)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

pref_edit.py

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>pref_edit</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for user_data_type_detail in user_data_type_details %}
    <div>
        <label for="{{ user_data_type_detail.user_data_type_name }}">{{ user_data_type_detail.user_data_type_name }}</label>
        <select name="{{ user_data_type_detail.user_data_type_name }}">
            {% for ro in user_data_type_detail.response_options %}
                <option value="{{ ro.response_option_name }}">{{ ro.response_option_name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

[image: first language]

[image: second language]

#### Other possible solutions

There are other solutions if you are willing to change your database design to move `language_id` out of `UserDataType` and `ResponseOption` tables and into new tables. Check [this](https://www.vertabelo.com/blog/data-modeling-for-multiple-languages-how-to-design-a-localization-ready-system/) interesting article for different approaches.

Comment: Thanks, very useful and insightful answer. Yes, language needs to be handled in a different way, outside of UserDataType and ResponsOption tables. I'm working on approach #4 in the tutorial you suggested, but I'm having difficulties. Will add a follow up question.

Answer (score 0):

When trying out approach #4 for the multi-languange support in the article suggested, I'm having problems filtering out the languages that the logged-in user has set as the preferred language (also stored in the database). I still get all UserDataTypes and ResponseOptions (in all languages), so I'm missing something fundamental.

Data base class definitions are now:

```
class UserDataType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    user_data_type_name = db.Column(db.Text) #but not intending to use
    user_data_type_description = db.Column(db.Text) #but not intending to use
    udt_phrases = db.relationship('UdtTranslation', viewonly=True)
    response_options = db.relationship('ResponseOption', secondary="user_data_type_response_option", viewonly=True)

class UdtTranslation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'udt_translation'
    udt_trans_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_data_type.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    udt_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('language.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    udt_name = db.Column(db.Text) #the actual name in all languages
    udt_description = db.Column(db.Text) #the actual description in all languages

class ResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    response_option_name = db.Column(db.Text) #but not intending to use
    response_option_description = db.Column(db.Text) #but not intending to use
    ro_phrases = db.relationship('RoTranslation', viewonly=True)
    ro_languages = db.relationship('Language', secondary="ro_translation", viewonly=True)

class RoTranslation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ro_translation'
    ro_trans_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('response_option.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    ro_language_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('language.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    ro_name = db.Column(db.Text)  #the actual name in all languages
    ro_description = db.Column(db.Text) #the actual description in all languages

class Language(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'language'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    language_name = db.Column(db.Text)

class UserDataTypeResponseOption(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_data_type_response_option'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    user_data_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_data_type.id'))
    response_option_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('response_option.id'))
    response_option = db.relationship("ResponseOption", backref="parent_associations")
```

And the query I'm trying with is:

```
user_data_type_details = UserDataType.query.filter(UserDataType.id.in_(user_data_types)). \
    join(UserDataTypeResponseOption, UserDataType.id == UserDataTypeResponseOption.user_data_type_id). \
    join(UdtTranslation, UdtTranslation.udt_trans_id == UserDataType.id).filter_by(udt_language_id = language_pref). \
    join(ResponseOption, ResponseOption.id == UserDataTypeResponseOption.response_option_id). \
    join(RoTranslation, RoTranslation.ro_trans_id == ResponseOption.id).filter_by(ro_language_id = language_pref).all()
```

And with the below print routine I get the UserDataTypes in all languages, and for each UserDataType instance I get the ResponseOptions in all languages. So clearly the way I filter out the language isn't working. Ideas?

```
for user_data_type_detail in user_data_type_details:
   for udt_phrase in user_data_type_detail.udt_phrases:
       print(udt_phrase.udt_name)
        for ro in user_data_type_detail.response_options:
            for ro_phrase in ro.ro_phrases:
                print(ro_phrase.ro_name)
```